# How to Submit Value, but Receive Key from Input field ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, key-value

I have an id received in my action parameter. From where I got my scheme details. By this details I found my desired scheme name. And now I want to show this name in my .cshtml as an input field where I want to show the value in "read-only" format (not changeable). So in my controller I sent it inside a `ViewData` instead of SelectList as shown below:

```
 ViewData["SchemeNum"] = schemeInfo.SchemeNum;
```

instead of

```
ViewData["SchemeInfoId"] = new SelectList(_context.PackagewiseSchemeInfo.Where(p => p.Id == id), "Id", "SchemeNum", schemeInfo.SchemeNum);
```

I know if I use a selectlist, it would have been easier for me to catch the `Key` after form submitting like mentioned above -- "Id", "SchemeNum" ...

HTML:

```
<input  class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.SchemeNum" readonly />
```

Now, I'm getting `SchemeNum` instead of `Id` after form submission. I want to know how to catch the KEY instead of value by an input tag? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanna disable your input add a hidden field for the id.

```
<input class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.SchemeNum" disabled />
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.SchemeId" />
```

Comment: This is how i usually do. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Besides,you could custom Model Binder to get the matched key of the value.

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class PackagewiseSchemeInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SchemeNum { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model PackagewiseSchemeInfo
<form asp-action="Test">
    <input asp-for="SchemeNum" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.SchemeNum" readonly />
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form>
```

Custom Model Binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;
    public CustomModelBinder(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }
        var data = bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["SchemeNum"];
        var model = _context.PackagewiseSchemeInfo.Where(a => a.SchemeNum == data.ToString())
                                                  .Select(a=>a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var schemeInfo = new PackagewiseSchemeInfo()
    {
        Id = 1,
        SchemeNum = "aaa"
    };
    ViewData["SchemeNum"] = schemeInfo.SchemeNum;
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]int Id)
{
     //do your stuff...
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I hope this works. But isn't it a long process to do such job ? is there any short way ?
Thanks Alot

Comment: I think it is not a long process.But for a short way, I think it should be what Max did to pass a hidden input.

Comment: Ok i understand. Thanks Alot Rena . I appreciate your effort !